# Can I put multiple items into the same publish transaction using Core Service?

Tags: 2011, core-service, publishing

I want to publish several components from a core service client application at the same time within a single publish transaction. I thought [this post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/329/to-ensure-they-publish-simultaneously-is-it-possible-to-publish-pages-and-compo) might tell me the answer, but while it gives some options (using custom resolvers/templating code) these are not applicable in my case, as the logic to choose which components to publish lies in the application code, and cannot be put in a resolver/template.

I noticed that if I use:

```
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.Publish(string[] ids, 
       PublishInstructionData publishInstruction, string[] targets, 
       PublishPriority? priority, ReadOptions readOptions)
```

A separate transaction is created for each item and target combination. Is it possible to have all the items in one transaction per target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently adding multiple items into a single transaction can be accomplished in some scenarios.

- In tridion 2013 you can group them in a bundle and publish the bundle, it will generate a single transaction.
- Publish a Structure Group, it will generate a single transaction for all the organizational items within the Structure Group.

Unfortunately the source code you used as a sample will always create multiple transactions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Will IncludeChildPublications really create a single transaction? I thought that different publications always had different transactions (as they could go to totally different deployers)

Comment: Hi Will, My understanding is that the same publication target should be configured in parents and children publications, so the item will eventually be published to the same target (same destinations) in a single transaction.

Comment: No - you always get a different transaction per publishing context.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, it seems right, IncludeChildPublications will generate one transaction per publication context.